# Array becomes undefined after a function is run

Tags: php, arrays

So, in the code, I have this

```
$availableOptions = array( 'run' => 'runs a script',
                           'list' => 'list all available scripts',
                           'help' => 'shows help');
....
elseif (in_array($option, $availableOptions)) {
    echo "- " . greenString($option) . " - " . $availableOptions[$option];
    echo "- " . greenString("SYNTAX: ") . $optionsSyntaxes[$option];
    echo greenString("-------------------------------\n\n");
}
```

But for some reason, it evaluates to false no matter what I put. So I tried it in an interactive shell and when I don't run the function and run var_dump($availableOptions), it works fine. When I add the function then try it, it fails even if I redeclare it manually. It's really weird.

```
php > help();
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function greenString() in php shell code on line 9
php > var_dump($availableOptions);
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: availableOptions in php shell code on line 1
NULL
php > $availableOptions = array( 'run' => 'runs a script', 'list' => 'list all available scripts', 'help' => 'shows help');
php > var_dump($availableOptions);
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: availableOptions in php shell code on line 1
NULL
```

Before running it:

```
php > var_dump($availableOptions);
array(3) {
  ["run"]=>
  string(13) "runs a script"
  ["list"]=>
  string(26) "list all available scripts"
  ["help"]=>
  string(10) "shows help"
}
php >
```

Comment: Please show us the function

Comment: `undefined function greenString()` so it doesn't know what greenString() is

Comment: I added that in, but either way I don't see how that should change the array being defined or not.

Comment: `elseif (isset($availableOptions[$option])) `.... in_array is testing against the __values__ in an array, it looks as though you should be testing against the __keys__

Comment: Oh, that solved it perfectly. I changed it to array_key_exists() and it works perfectly now. Thanks! :D